# Weirdly-behaving recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I was recently fooling around on my calculator, and found a recurrence relation that behaves **very** weirdly (it started looking like a mutilated combination of sine graphs at some points, presumably due to some sort oscillation due to the subtraction):

$$a_n=1-\dfrac{a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}}, \qquad a_1 = a,  \qquad a_2 = b$$

Is there any explicit (non-recursive) formula for $a_n$ in this recurrence relation? Or is it just not possible to find it? If it's not possible to find it, are there any values of $a$ and $b$ that allow for a solution (similarly to the logistic map)?

Also, if at all possible, would it be possible to show work for this monstrosity?

Answer (score 1):

If you ever get two successive values that are equal you get division by zero in two more steps.  You can't alternate between two values, because to go $a,b,a,b,\ldots$ you need $$a=1-\frac ba\\b=1-\frac ab\\a^2=a-b\\b^2=b-a$$ and one of the squares must be negative.  I ran $500$ iterations for a few starting values.  Each time I got a pair of values in the hundreds when two preceding values were very close.  It looks quite chaotic.

If you allow the values to be complex, you can alternate between $1+i$ and $1-i$ but that seems to be an unstable equilibrium.

Comment: If the sequence is undefined past a certain point, would one consider it to have an explicit formula? (not what I was looking for, though)

Comment: It is only undefined for some starting values.  You can certainly find an  explicit formulas for each of the $a_n$ but they quickly become a mess.  I would be surprised if somebody finds a nice one for all $n$, but I have been surprised before.

Comment: I would be surprised if a messy one was found for all $n$! People can find surprising things when they're knowledgeable and determined.

Answer (score 1):

To add yet another partial answer, there certainly is a fixed cycle of size 3. It starts with $(a,b)=(1.347296355333858, 2.5320888862379594)$, and seems to be unstable (that is, small deviations from it tend to grow). Worse yet, it seems to be unstable ***both ways***: you may iterate backwards to find $a_0$, $a_{-1}$, $a_{-2}$ and so on, and still the small deviations will grow. Other than that, the backwards iteration is relatively well-behaved, in that it tends to converge after a brief period of chaos. Not that it helps us much, though.

Yes, I guess no explicit formula is to be found, and yes, this thing looks pretty much as chaotic as the logistic map (even though the latter *does* have an explicit formula at $r=4$). I guess there are fixed cycles of all sizes, and they all are unstable (otherwise we would have stumbled upon one by now).

Comment: After looking at the graph, I should've immediately known I stumbled up upon chaos theory.

Comment: How did you get those numbers? I assume by setting $a_1=a_4$ and $a_2=a_5$?

Comment: That's right.$\!$